# iOS crash reporting, e.g. during beta testing

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios, crash

I'll be ready to start beta testing my iPhone app in the next month, and I guess I should be expecting it to crash once or twice. It would be nice to get the crash report -- and whatever supporting info I can -- back to the mothership. Ideally, this would require little to no work on the part of the beta testers.

There are tools and methods. So far for me, the most promising contender is [CrashKit](http://parveenkaler.com/2010/08/11/crashkit-helping-your-iphone-apps-suck-less/). I've also looked at [Crash Reporter](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/Crash_Reporter.20090129.html). And I've reviewed these Craig Hockenberry posts (["debugging with backups"](http://furbo.org/2008/11/10/debugging-with-backups/), ["symbolicatifination"](http://furbo.org/2008/08/08/symbolicatifination/)) from 2008.

Am I overlooking something obvious? Any further advice, folks?

Answer (score 5):

I've been using Crittercism for crash reporting and getting feedback.

http://www.crittercism.com

Answer (score 4):

Check out the iOS notifier for Airbrake.

http://airbrakeapp.com/

Comment: Thanks, Marshall. Will definitely be checking it out.

Comment: The stack traces on hoptoad are pretty un-reliable, very often giving 0x0 as names.   Try this one for a more robust solution.  I'm close to moving over to it.  https://github.com/therealkerni/crashreporterdemo

Comment: If you are getting 0x0 names it means your have symbol stripping on. See the notes section about how to configure your app to remove stripping: https://github.com/guicocoa/hoptoad-ios